# how to get image in listview using json parsing android

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-listview, android-gridview

I want to create a ListView with JSON parsing from a URL.

In my ListView I want images from the url to match the width of the ListView. Additionally, clicking a next button should open a new Activity. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a proper question @Sahil. you have to show your work and explicitly point out what are you asking in your work.

Comment: hi , i want a listview with only images . images parse from url seee                 http://www.learn2crack.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Screenshot-from-2013-11-02-202518.png         i want images from url in the listview . want full code of that . the code is different in different sites , i want the easiest code of this  @Ercan

Answer (score 0):

This question is vague and it is unlikely anybody is willing to just write this complex code for you.

**Here are some links to get you started:**

- [Creating a ListView](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)
- [Android universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
- [Using Android intents](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Good luck!